# How to do bulk update using elasticsearchOperations in Spring data elasticsearch?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

We were doing bullk insert by using bulkIndex as follow:

```
List<IndexQuery> indexQueries = new ArrayList<>();
        for (FooDocument fooDocument : fooDocuments) {
            IndexQuery query = new IndexQueryBuilder()
                    .withId(String.valueOf(fooDocument.getId()))
                    .withObject(fooDocument)
                    .build();
            indexQueries.add(query);
        }
    elasticsearchOperations.bulkIndex(indexQueries, IndexCoordinates.of("foo_index_3"));
```

We also want to use for bulk updates something like:

```
elasticsearchOperations.bulkUpdate(updateQueries, IndexCoordinates.of("foo_index_3"));
```

But bulkUpdate requires list of `UpdateQuery`.I am trying to create it by doing something like:

```
List<IndexQuery> updateQueries = new ArrayList<>();
        for (FooDocument fooDocument : fooDocuments) {
            UpdateQuery updateQuery = new UpdateQueryBuilder()//which Builder class and method is required?
                    .withId(String.valueOf(fooDocument.getId()))
                    .withObject(fooDocument)
                    .build();
            updateQueries.add(query);
        }
```

But unlike `IndexQueryBuilder` there is no `UpdateQueryBuilder()` available, what is the correct way to build the `UpdateQuery` and which `Builder` class should we use? I am wondering whether `UpdateQueryBuilder` class has been deprecated.

P.S: we are using `4.0.2.RELEASE` version of `spring-data-elasticsearch`

Comment: Have you tried `UpdateQuery.Builder()` ?

Comment: @Val, I am not aware about how to build it using it, all I have is id and Document as in IndexyQuery, was wondering whether same is possible with UpdateQuery, If you could provide the sample, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Are you updating all fields of the document or just a few?

Comment: @Val, we are using it for insertion, kinda updating like all fields, due to some reason, cannot use bulkIndex

Comment: Since you're updating all fields, why don't you simply reindex the document with `IndexQuery` instead?

Comment: @Val, we are reloading the data in different index but for bulkIndex, we were getting 'reason=action [indices:admin/create] is unauthorized for user' Error, so decided to use bulkUpdate

Comment: Ok, your user simply doesn't have the right to create a new index and it's not going to be different with an update query. But if you simply send `bulkIndex` with `IndexQuery` to the same index, then it should work...

Comment: What I meant is that whether index or update, the error you get is that you don't have the rights to create an index (I'm not talking about the right to create documents).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create an `UpdateQuery` with a builder like this:

```
UpdateQuerybuilder builder = UpdateQuery.builder(id)
   .with(...)
   .build();
```

Here the builder is a nested class and not a separate one.